# Continuous holidays

Tags: combinatorics

We are facing a problem in which we are 4 people and we have to avail 4 weeks/person summer vacation in a 7 week slot. Constraint is that at least one person should be available in the college. Is a schedule possible where the constraint is met and all the members can go for continuous 4 week vacation?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Every continuous allocation of 4 days in range from 1 to 7 uses day 4.